# ELOQUENT LARAVEL Cast integer to string column value in hasOne relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I want create one-to-one relationship into two tables.

One of my tables have column typed in int but the second have foreign key column typed in string.

Into database :

```
user table: 
id: int
```

---

```
life table:
user_id: string
```

in User model :

```
public function life(Builder $query): HasOne
{
    return $query->hasOne(Life::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Any help is appreciated to answer my question

Comment: I would consider changing the data type for `user_id` in your "life table" from string to an integer.

Comment: me too but i can't for multiples personal reasons